# Null parameter checking in C#

Tags: c#, function, null

In C#, are there any good reasons (other than a better error message) for adding parameter null checks to every function where null is not a valid value? Obviously, the code that uses s will throw an exception anyway. And such checks make code slower and harder to maintain.

```
void f(SomeType s)
{
  if (s == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("s cannot be null.");
  }

  // Use s
}
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that a simple null check will slow down your code by a significant (or even measurable) amount.

Comment: Well, it depends what "Use s" does. If all it does is "return s.SomeField" then the extra check will probably slow down the method by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @kaalus: Probably? Probably doesn't cut it in my book. Where is your test data? And how likely is it that such a change would be the bottleneck of your application in the first place?

Comment: @Jon: you're right I don't have hard data here. If you develop for Windows Phone or Xbox where JIT inlining will be affected by this extra "if", and where branching is very expensive, you may get quite paranoid.

Comment: @kaalus: So adjust your code style in those very specific cases *after proving that it makes a significant difference* or use Debug.Assert (again, only in those situations, see Eric's answer) so that the checks are only on in certain builds.

Comment: To add to the 'serious doubt' :-) of the first commenter, a typical compiler optimisation is to eliminate an implicit null check if (data flow analysis shows) there is a previous null check. Therefore, it quite often really is the case that inserting an explicit null check does not add any execution time at all. Even if this isn't so, a typical modern super-scalar processor is likely to be able to execute the check in effectively zero time, because it can execute the check in parallel with doing other things.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Yes, there are good reasons:

- It identifies exactly what is null, which may not be obvious from a `NullReferenceException`
- It makes the code fail on invalid input even if some other condition means that the value isn't dereferenced
- It makes the exception occur *before* the method could have any other side-effects you might reach before the first dereference
- It means you can be confident that if you pass the parameter into something else, you're not violating *their* contract
- It documents your method's requirements (using [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/contracts) is even better for that of course)

Now as for your objections:

- *It's slower*: Have you found this to *actually* be the bottleneck in your code, or are you guessing? Nullity checks are very quick, and in the vast majority of cases they're *not* going to be the bottleneck
- *It makes the code harder to maintain*: I think the opposite. I think it's *easier* to use code where it's made crystal clear whether or not a parameter can be null, and where you're confident that that condition is enforced.

And for your assertion:

> Obviously, the code that uses s will throw an exception anyway.

Really? Consider:

```
void f(SomeType s)
{
  // Use s
  Console.WriteLine("I've got a message of {0}", s);
}
```

That uses `s`, but it doesn't throw an exception. If it's invalid for `s` to be null, and that indicates that something's wrong, an exception is the most appropriate behaviour here.

Now *where* you put those argument validation checks is a different matter. You may decide to trust all the code within your own class, so not bother on private methods. You may decide to trust the rest of your assembly, so not bother on internal methods. You should almost certainly validate the arguments for public methods.

A side note: the single-parameter constructor overload of `ArgumentNullException` should just be the parameter name, so your test should be:

```
if (s == null)
{
  throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
}
```

Alternatively you can create an extension method, allowing the somewhat terser:

```
s.ThrowIfNull("s");
```

In my version of the (generic) extension method, I make it return the original value if it's non null, allowing you to write things like:

```
this.name = name.ThrowIfNull("name");
```

You can also have an overload which doesn't take the parameter name, if you're not too bothered about that.

#### Update .NET 6

There is a [new method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception.throwifnull?view=net-6.0) in .NET API which simplifies `null` check syntax.

```
 ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(someParameter);
```

Comment: +1 for the extension method.  I've done the exact same thing, including other validation such as `ThrowIfEmpty` on `ICollection`

Comment: Why I think it's harder to maintain: as with every manual mechanism that requires programmer intervention every time, this is prone to mistakes and omissions and clutters the code. Flaky safety is worse than no safety at all.

Comment: @kaalus: Do you apply the same attitude to testing? "My tests won't catch all possible bugs, therefore I won't write any"? When the safety mechanisms *do* work, they'll make it easier to find the problem and reduce impact elsewhere (by catching the problem earlier). If that happens 9 times out of 10, that's still better than it happening 0 times out of 10...

Comment: @JonSkeet, if using `if (x == null)` to check for a null value, then there is no need for `Debug.Assert`? When would you advocate to use one over the other? Should both be used simultaneously & extensively?

Comment: @DoctorOreo: I don't use `Debug.Assert`. It's even more important to catch errors in production (before they screw up real data) than in development.

Comment: @JonSkeet Any chance we could see the code to your ThrowIfNull extension?  I know it's pretty straightforward, but would be nice to see how you implemented it.

Comment: @JoshNoe: It would be the equivalent of `CheckNotNull` here: https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime/Utility/Preconditions.cs - but as an extension method.

Comment: Is this answer strictly for throwing null argument exceptions? For example, I have a method like `bool TestSomething<T>(T someClass)`. Would a better design be to throw an exception, or return false in this case? Or is this one of those "it depends on your intent" sort of things?

Comment: @KyleBaran: Without knowing what `TestSomething` is meant to do, we can't possibly know whether it's valid for the value to be null. It could be a method designed specifically to handle null input. I think the main thing is to make sure it's clear what the caller should expect.

Comment: Now with C# 6.0 we can even use  ``throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s))``

Comment: @JonSkeet Why did you prefer an extension method over a static class in this case? Of course, the extension syntax makes it shorter. However, the extension might conflict with existing code and analysis tools might warn about possible null references when invoking ````ThrowIfnull````itself.

Comment: @NiklasPeter: Well the extension method has to *be* in a static class already, of course. In practice I now don't use extension methods for this, just to avoid cluttering up Intellisense. Oh, and of course I use nameof everywhere...

Comment: Are there any good statistics or benchmarks on how much it does slow a typical code base down by checking null constantly?

Comment: @rolls: I'm not sure there's such a thing as a "typical" codebase. In Noda Time, we're very sensitive to performance everywhere, but still check all public input - and check internal input within debug builds (so that unit tests can pick up bugs).

Comment: Yeah I guess I was just after some rough ball park approximates with some examples. Eg can it actually change the UI experience.

Comment: @rolls: Well it still depends - if you're calling something which is otherwise trivial in a very tight loop, then it's going to be much more significant than something you only call occasionally. I've very rarely found it to be a problem.

Comment: C# 6.0 introduced "nameof" which should be used here instead of hardcoding the variable names so that names aren't changed and get out of sync with the logging messages.

Comment: @Asher: Agreed, and that's what I do now of course - but I'm not going to edit all my answers from 6 years ago...

Comment: My main concern is not performance or maintainability. It's readability. Having all some thousand methods in a code base start with null checks seems unsavory.

Comment: @sean: The C# design team is considering making it much simpler: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2145

Comment: Today, in year 2021, we use `this.name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s));` as a modern equivalent of what @JonSkeet suggested here as `this.name = name.ThrowIfNull("name");`

Comment: @Nabeel: Personally I still use a helper method of `Preconditions.CheckNotNull` (but using `nameof`). With C# 9 it should be possible to avoid even having to specify the `nameof` argument via `CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute`. (I haven't used that myself yet.)

Answer (score 53):

I agree with Jon, but I would add one thing to that.

My attitude about when to add explicit null checks is based on these premises:

- There should be a way for your unit tests to exercise every statement in a program.
- `throw` statements are *statements*.
- The consequence of an `if` is a *statement*.
- Therefore, there should be a way to exercise the `throw` in `if (x == null) throw whatever;`

If there is *no possible way* for that statement to be executed then it cannot be tested and should be replaced with `Debug.Assert(x != null);`.

If there is a possible way for that statement to be executed then write the statement, and then write a unit test that exercises it.

It is *particularly* important that public methods of public types check their arguments in this way; you have no idea what crazy thing your users are going to do. Give them the "hey you bonehead, you're doing it wrong!" exception as soon as possible.

Private methods of private types, by contrast, are much more likely to be in the situation where you control the arguments and can have a strong guarantee that the argument is never null; use an assertion to document that invariant.

Answer (score 33):

I've been using this for a year now:

```csharp
_ = s ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s));
```

It's a oneliner, and the discard (`_`) means there's no unnecessary allocation.

Comment: Only works with string types though.  Doesn't work with double etc.

Comment: @CorneliusJ.vanDyk it works with anything that CAN be null. `double` can't be null, so ofcourse it doesnt make sense there. But it'll work with `double?`.

Comment: very good syntax but not an answer of the original question.

Answer (score 9):

Without an explicit `if` check, it can be very difficult to figure out *what* was `null` if you don't own the code.

If you get a `NullReferenceException` from deep inside a library without source code, you're likely to have a lot of trouble figuring out what you did wrong.

These `if` checks will not make your code noticeably slower.

---

Note that the parameter to the [`ArgumentNullException` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception.-ctor#System_ArgumentNullException__ctor_System_String_) is a parameter name, not a message.
Your code should be

```cs
if (s == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
```

I wrote a code snippet to make this easier:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Check for null arguments</Title>
            <Shortcut>tna</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for throw new ArgumentNullException</Description>
            <Author>SLaks</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>Parameter</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Paremeter to check for null</ToolTip>
                    <Default>value</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[if ($Parameter$ == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("$Parameter$");
        $end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a look at [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992) if you need a nicer way to make sure you do not get any null objects as a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

In [C# 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11) preview it is super cool!!

You just need to add two exclamation marks `!!` at the end of the parameter name. This will do the null parameter checking.

```cs
void f(SomeType s!!)
{
    // Use s
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
void f(SomeType s)
{
    if (s is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s));
    }

    // Use s
}
```

A good explanation article about it can be found [here](https://endjin.com/blog/2022/02/csharp-11-preview-parameter-null-checking).

Comment: Is it present in the current C# 11 release?

Comment: This didn't actually make it into the final release.

Answer (score 3):

It saves some debugging, when you hit that exception.

The ArgumentNullException states explicitly that it was "s" that was null.

If you don't have that check and let the code blow up, you get a NullReferenceException from some unidentified line in that method. In a release build you don't get line numbers!

Answer (score 2):

The main benefit is that you're being explicit with the requirements of your method right from the start. This makes it clear to other developers working on the code that it is truly an error for a caller to send a null value to your method.

The check will also halt the execution of the method before any other code executes. That means you won't have to worry about modifications being made by the method that are left unfinished.

Answer (score 0):

Original code:

```
void f(SomeType s)
{
  if (s == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("s cannot be null.");
  }

  // Use s
}
```

Rewrite it as:

```
void f(SomeType s)
{
  if (s == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s));
}
```

The reason to rewrite using `nameof` is that it allows for easier refactoring. If the name of your variable `s` ever changes, then the debugging messages will be updated as well, whereas if you just hardcode the name of the variable, then it will eventually be outdated when updates are made over time. It's a good practice used in the industry.

Answer (score -2):

```
int i = Age ?? 0;
```

So for your example:

```
if (age == null || age == 0)
```

Or:

```
if (age.GetValueOrDefault(0) == 0)
```

Or:

```
if ((age ?? 0) == 0)
```

Or ternary:

```
int i = age.HasValue ? age.Value : 0;
```