# Data insert error - object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-insert

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //    try
    //    {
    DateTime admission = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpadmission.Value);
    DateTime expiry = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpexpirydate.Value);
    DateTime release = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpreleasedate.Value);
    DateTime amount = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpreceiptamount.Value);
    DateTime warrant = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpwarrantdate.Value);

    //dLayer.insertadmitcivilprison(admission.ToString(), txtpmsno.Text.ToString(), txtname.Text.ToString(), txtfname.Text.ToString(), cmbgender.SelectedItem.ToString(), txtoccupation.Text, txtvillage.Text, txtdistrict.Text, txtheight.Text, txtphesiogamy.Text, txtage.Text, cmbresidence.SelectedItem.ToString(), txtcaste.Text, txteducation.Text, txtpolicestation.Text, txtcolor.Text, txtidentification.Text, Txtwhichprison.Text, txtwhytransfered.Text, txtsrnoformerprison.Text, txtnamedetainingcreditor.Text, txtamountofclaim.Text, txtsentenceauthority.Text, txtcauseofdetention.Text, txtwarrantno.Text, warrant.ToString(), expiry.ToString(), release.ToString(), txtweightondischarge.Text, txtweightonadmission.Text, txtrealeaseauthority.Text, txtdurationimprisonment.Text, txtdailydietmonety.Text, txtamountreceived.Text, amount.ToString(), txtprivateproperty.Text, txtbalanceleft.Text, txtbalancedisposedoff.Text);
    //MessageBox.Show("Data inserted Successfully");
    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(dLayer.con, CommandType.Text, "insert into pcms.tbl_prisoner_detail (date_of_admission,pmsno,pname,pfname,sex,last_occupation,address,district,height,phesiogamy,age,residence,caste,education_qualification,police_station,color,identification_mark,previous_prison,transfer_reason,registration_no_pre_prison,reason_for_detention,amount_of_claim,sentencing_authority,reason_for_detention,warrant_no,date_of_warrant,expiry_date_imprisonment,date_of_release,weight_on_discharge,weight_on_admission,authority_of_discharge,imprisionment_duration,daily_diet_allowance_granted,amount_received,date_of_recieve,property_recieved,balance_left,balance_disposed_off) values('" + admission.ToString() + "','" + txtpmsno.Text + "','" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtfname.Text + "','" + cmbgender.SelectedItem.ToString() + "','" + txtoccupation.Text + "','" + txtvillage.Text + "','" + txtdistrict.Text + "','" + txtheight.Text + "','" + txtphesiogamy.Text + "','" + txtage.Text + "','" + cmbresidence.SelectedItem.ToString() + "','" + txtcaste.Text + "','" + txteducation.Text + "','" + txtpolicestation.Text + "','" + txtcolor.Text + "','" + txtidentification.Text + "','" + Txtwhichprison.Text + "','" + txtwhytransfered.Text + "','" + txtsrnoformerprison.Text + "','" + txtnamedetainingcreditor.Text + "','" + txtamountofclaim.Text + "','" + txtsentenceauthority.Text + "','" + txtcauseofdetention.Text + "','" + txtwarrantno.Text + "','" + warrant.ToString() + "','" + expiry.ToString() + "','" + release.ToString() + "','" + txtweightondischarge.Text + "','" + txtweightonadmission.Text + "','" + txtrealeaseauthority.Text + "','" + txtdurationimprisonment.Text + "','" + txtdailydietmonety.Text + "','" + txtamountreceived.Text + "','" + amount.ToString() + "','" + txtprivateproperty.Text + "','" + txtbalanceleft.Text + "','" + txtbalancedisposedoff.Text + "')");
}
```

Code on data layer:

```
public void insertadmitcivilprison(string dateofadmission,string pmsno, string prisonername, string prisonerfathername, string gender, string occupation, string village, string district, string height, string phesiogamy, string age, string residence, string caste, string education, string police_station, string color, string identification_mark, string from_which_prison, string why_trasfered, string PMS_in_former_prison, string detaining_creditor, string amount_of_claim, string sentencing_authority, string cause_of_detention, string warrant_no, string warrant_date, string expiry_date_imprisonment, string release_date, string weight_on_discharge, string weight_on_admission, string authority_for_release, string duration_imprisonment, string diet_money, string amount_received, string date_receipt_amount, string private_property, string balance_left, string balance_disposedoff)
{
    //CallingSystem.SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(con, CommandType.Text, "insert into pcms.tbl_prisoner_detail(pmsno,pname,pfname,pms_no,finger_type,user_status,userid,bal_amount,canteen_bal_amount,reg_date) values('" + pmsno + "','" + prisonername + "','" + prisonerfathername + "','" + pms_no + "','" + finger_type + "','" + user_status + "','" + userid + "','" + bal_amount + "','" + canteen_bal_amount + "','" + reg_date + "')");
    CallingSystem.SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(con, CommandType.Text, "insert into pcms.tbl_prisoner_detail (date_of_admission,pmsno,pname,pfname,sex,last_occupation,address,district,height,phesiogamy,age,residence,caste,education_qualification,police_station,color,identification_mark,previous_prison,transfer_reason,registration_no_pre_prison,reason_for_detention,amount_of_claim,sentencing_authority,reason_for_detention,warrant_no,date_of_warrant,expiry_date_imprisonment,date_of_release,weight_on_discharge,weight_on_admission,authority_of_discharge,imprisionment_duration,daily_diet_allowance_granted,amount_received,date_of_recieve,property_recieved,balance_left,balance_disposed_off) values('" + dateofadmission + "','" + pmsno + "','" + prisonername + "','" + prisonerfathername + "','" + gender + "','" + occupation + "','" + village + "','" + district + "','" + height + "','" + phesiogamy + "','" + age + "','" + residence + "','" + caste + "','" + education + "','" + police_station + "','" + color + "','" + identification_mark + "','" + from_which_prison + "','" + why_trasfered + "','" + PMS_in_former_prison + "','" + detaining_creditor + "','" + amount_of_claim + "','" + sentencing_authority + "','" + cause_of_detention + "','" + warrant_no + "','" + warrant_date + "','" + expiry_date_imprisonment + "','" + release_date + "','" + weight_on_discharge + "','" + weight_on_admission + "','" + authority_for_release + "','" + duration_imprisonment + "','" + diet_money + "','" + amount_received + "','" + date_receipt_amount + "','" + private_property + "','" + balance_left + "','" + balance_disposedoff + "')");
}
```

Comment: which line did the error takes place?

Comment: line number 12 of button click i.e sqlhelper.executenonquery

Comment: Did you properly instantiate `Sqlhelper` class? like `SQLHelper Sqlhelper = new SqlHelper();`

Comment: i didn't create any instantiate,i had used SQLHelper  this only

Answer (score 0):

One or some of that .Value s coming null. You can check them with if conditions. I also recommend you to use parameters instead of giving values directly to sql command. You can find some good tips here: [Null parameter checking in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585493/null-parameter-checking-in-c-sharp/7585528#7585528)

Answer (score 0):

`dtpadmission.Value ,dtpexpirydate.Value , etc..` In those statement, if it is `dtpadmission`,`dtpexpirydate` or any of dates are null ,then cannot read the value from it.It returns object null reference.So better to check those properties are null or not and then set it to the statement.You can do it like as follows.

```
 DateTime admission = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpadmission != null ? dtpadmission.Value.ToString() : null ); // Instead of setting null value you can set the efault value here
```

OR

in this `dLayer.con` just check the dLayer object is null or not.

And also if the ToString() methods which you use in like `amount.ToString()` if they are (`amount,etc..)` null then occurs the same.

Comment: but it gives   Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker' to type 'System.IConvertible'. error

Comment: what are the data types of dtpadmission,etc.. i thought that its return string?

Comment: datatype is datetime,null

Comment: then why do you convert it.If they are DateTime no need to convert it ryt?

Comment: then what i have to use with datetimepicker

Comment: WHEN i have used simple value with datetimepicker then it gives same error object refrenec not set to an instance

Comment: You can use it like this  'DateTime admission = dtpadmission != null ? dtpadmission .Value : DateTime.MinValue;'